# Retrieve Data with second .child method from Firebase Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

To explain my issue you need to see my Database structure first:

[image: Datastructure]

What I want to do is to retrieve only the Name from the Node "1000" 
That's what I did so far:

```
var datref: DatabaseReference!
    datref = Database.database().reference()
    datref.child("QRBereich").child("1000").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{

            let qrbar = QRBar(dictionary: dict)
            qrbar.setValuesForKeys(dict)

            qrbarname.append(qrbar.Name!) }
    }

        , withCancel: nil)
```

But this gives me just an empty array. When I delete ".child("1000")" I receive the names from the nodes 1000(barracuda) and 2000(deluxxe). But what I need is only the name "Barracuda" from the node 1000.

QRBar is a model and is written as follow:

```
import Foundation
class QRBar: NSObject {
var Name: String?

init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.Name = dictionary["Name"] as? String ?? ""


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need the `.value` event:

```
datref.child("QRBereich").child("1000").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

You'd use `.childAdded` if you're listening for all children under `QRBereich`.